# New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.module.spec.service

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

My project is  is a maven web project run on JBoss Application Server 7.1.1 with some modules in pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
</modules>
```

module A need use Jasper Report for report function
i add dependences for Jasper to pom.xml of module A

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

i rebuild deploy and start the server. I get this error

> New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-digester-1.7.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.itext-2.1.7.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar".main, JBAS014799: ... and 36 more ]

if i comment the Jasper dependence on file pom.xml of module A. This error not appear. I have checked that the .jar file of Jasper exist in Java Build Path (Maven Dependence)

when i replaces  dependences

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

i also get similarly error

> INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
>   JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.lucene-core-4.5.1.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-lang-2.3.jar".main, JBAS014799: ... and 48 more ] 
>         service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-collections-3.2.1.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.lucene-core-4.5.1.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.commons-lang-2.3.jar".main, JBAS014799: ... and 48 more ]

How to fix this error ? Thank for any help

Answer (score 1):

[JasperReports](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.0) has internal dependencies on a lot of other libraries.

Your log is pointing out that your `ntms-standalone-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear` has dependencies on:

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
```

and 36 more dependencies.

These are all due to JasperReports. If you need to include jasper, please include all the other libraries and provide them as a [custom module](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1933) to your JBOSS AS 7.

Comment: bad new is i try replace JasperReports dependences with another Report dependences. This error also happen.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen, even [dynamicreports](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.dynamicreports/dynamicreports-core/4.1.0) has certain compile time dependencies. You will need to include those for JBOSS to recognize and run them. That is how it works. In a modular fashion.

Comment: yeah, I try replace JasperReports dependences with Xalan dependence. This error not happen.